# Chrome not updating policy list from /Library/Preferences/com.google.Chrome.plist

Tags: google-chrome, mac, group-policy

My swift program periodically updates the `com.google.Chrome.plist` file stored in `/Library/Preferences`.

During the initial executions, it just needs a restart of Chrome browser for the policies to take effect. But now I need to restart the system to make the policies to take effect. How do I get it to update without restarting the Mac?

And also the `Reload policies` button in `chrome://policy` won't do the trick. (I wonder what's its purpose?)

And also, please explain the difference between placing the plist file in `/Library/Preferences` and in `/Library/Managed Preferences`

Thank you!

Comment: Or is there any command like `gpupdate /force` ( in Windows ) in mac to force update the Preferences. Similar question: [Refresh Chrome policies programmatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44675258/refresh-chrome-policies-programmatically)

Answer (score 1):

The reason is, from Mac OS Mavericks, apple started to cache plist files, which results in replacing a plist file manually has no effect until the cache is reloaded automatically. If you open the application which uses this plist file to early, it overwrites your copied file with the old/cached one.

To reload the preference file manually, use `defaults read <filename>.plist` to read the new plist values.

Source: [nethack](https://nethack.ch/2014/03/30/quick-tip-flush-os-x-mavericks-plist-file-cache/)

Now, I just use a `sh` script to call the `defaults` after executing my program.